# c++ gsl interaction between objects in ode

Tags: c++, object, gsl, interaction, ode

Would you please help me with my problem. I'm trying to write a program where objects in different class interact. I base my model on the gsl library to resolve my ordinary differential equations (ode).

Instances of different classes consume each other, so they get or loose mass when they eat or are eaten.

My 2 ode are like b[i] = sum of consumption - sum of consumed. *I calculate consumption as follow, with 1 being the consumer and 0, the prey.* 
    conso[1] = y[0] * x[1] * y[1]

The original code comes from "sample code using gsl routines" as follow with modifications. *The instances of class A and B are included in maps of class C.*

I'm new to c++ and I don't see how I can integrate a loop in the ode to make it calculate what has been consumed by each instance, and remove it from the other instances that have been eaten. The best would be to use functions and variables that are in the istances class but the function where the ode are has to be static. I thought about array but it seems that arrays can't be parameters of the odes.

The other problem is that for each instance, the parameters has to change and be taken in the class, but how I did here, in the loop with the iterators, the ode will work for the last instance... Again I would have like to use an array of class C that take the parameter of the instances in class A and B, but because the function is static I can't use the array of the class "C". I'm in real trouble !
Do you have any ideas ? Thank you !

```
// include files
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv.h>

// ************************* C.h ****************************

class C
{
public :
C(std::map(std::map<std::string,A> &A, std::map<std::string,B> &B);
~C();
int integ(void);
int static rhs (double t, const double y[], double f[], void *params_ptr);

private :
std::map<std::string,A> &A,
std::map<std::string,B> &B,

};

//*************************** C.cpp ****************************

int C::integ (void)
{
int dimension = 2;      // number of differential equations

double eps_abs = 1.e-8; // absolute error requested
double eps_rel = 1.e-10;    // relative error requested

// define the type of routine for making steps:
const gsl_odeiv_step_type *type_ptr = gsl_odeiv_step_rkf45;

// allocate/initialize the stepper, the control function, and the
//  evolution function.

gsl_odeiv_step *step_ptr = gsl_odeiv_step_alloc (type_ptr, dimension);
gsl_odeiv_control *control_ptr = gsl_odeiv_control_y_new (eps_abs, eps_rel);
gsl_odeiv_evolve *evolve_ptr = gsl_odeiv_evolve_alloc (dimension);

gsl_odeiv_system my_system; // structure with the rhs function, etc.

// parameter for the diffeq

    for(itA=A.begin(); itA!=A.end(); ++itA)
{
x = itA->second.getx();
my_system.params = &x;  // parameters to pass to rhs
}
for(itB=B.begin(); itB!=B.end(); ++itB)
{
z = itB->second.getz();
my_system.params = &z;  // parameters to pass to rhs
}


double y[2];            // current solution vector

double t, t_next;       // current and next independent variable
double tmin, tmax, delta_t; // range of t and step size for output

double h = 1e-6;        // starting step size for ode solver

// load values into the my_system structure
my_system.function = rhs;   // the right-hand-side functions dy[i]/dt
my_system.dimension = dimension;    // number of diffeq's


tmin = 0.;          // starting t value
tmax = 100.;            // final t value
delta_t = 1.;

for(itA=A.begin(); itA!=A.end(); ++itA)
{
y[0] = itA->second.getY();          // initial y value
}
for(itB=B.begin(); itB!=B.end(); ++itB)
{
y[1] = itB->second.getY();          // initial y value
}


t = tmin;           // initialize t

// print initial values
cout << scientific << setprecision (5) << setw (12) << t << " "
<< setw (12) << y[0] << " " << setw (12) << y[1] << endl;

// step to tmax from tmin
for (t_next = tmin + delta_t; t_next <= tmax; t_next += delta_t)
{
    while (t < t_next)  // evolve from t to t_next
    {
        gsl_odeiv_evolve_apply (evolve_ptr, control_ptr, step_ptr,
                                &my_system, &t, t_next, &h, y);
    }

    // print at t = t_next
    cout << scientific << setprecision (5) << setw (12) << t << " "
    << setw (12) << y[0] << " " << setw (12) << y[1] << endl;
}

// all done; free up the gsl_odeiv stuff
gsl_odeiv_evolve_free (evolve_ptr);
gsl_odeiv_control_free (control_ptr);
gsl_odeiv_step_free (step_ptr);

return 0;
}

//*************************** rhs ****************************

int C :: rhs (double , const double y[], double f[], void *params_ptr)
{
// get parameter(s) from params_ptr; here, just a double
double x = *(double *) params_ptr;
double z = *(double *) params_ptr;

// evaluate the right-hand-side functions at t
f[1] = x * y[1] + sum consumption - sum consumed;     //objects of class A
f[0] = - z * y[0] - sum consumed;   //objects of class B

return GSL_SUCCESS;     // GSL_SUCCESS defined in gsl/errno.h as 0
}
```

I tried to add consumption, but it says "error: 'void' must be the first and only parameter if
      specified" :

```
int C :: rhs (double , const double y[], double f[], void *params_ptr, void conso)
{
// get parameter(s) from params_ptr; here, just a double
double x = *(double *) params_ptr;
double z = *(double *) params_ptr;

// evaluate the right-hand-side functions at t
f[0] = z * y[0];     //objects of class A
f[1] = - x * y[1] + conso;   //objects of class B

return GSL_SUCCESS;     // GSL_SUCCESS defined in gsl/errno.h as 0
}

//***And in int C :: integ :

for(itA=A.begin(); itA!=A.end(); ++itA)
{
    for(itB=B.begin(); itB!=B.end(); ++itB)
    {
        void conso = itA->second.conso(itB->second, x);
    }
}

//***With in class A : 

void A :: conso(Group &prey, double x)
{
  double conso=0;
  conso = x * y * prey.gety();
}
```

Comment: It is very difficult to figure out what your problem is. I also think that your C++ code is confusing. Start with writing explicitly the equations you want to solve and try to formulate them in a vector equation dx_i/dt = f(x). Btw, you could also have a look at [odeint.com](http://odeint.com) a modern C++ library for solving ODEs.

Comment: Ok, I'll check this, thank you. If I don't figure it out, I'll come back. Sorry for the unclear, it's hard to explain well without writting 5 pages...

Comment: You definitely have a problem with the fact that rhs is a member function while GSL_FUNCTION only accepts global function without a wrapper.